# R- Summarize multiple values from custom function with ddply

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plyr

Is there a way to use `ddply` with a function that returns multiple values and combine these values in separate columns of a dataframe? I created a fictious example to illustrate what I mean.

```
#random data
ID <- rep(paste0("ID", 1:10), each=10)
x <- c(1:10)
y <- x+rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(ID=ID, x=x,y=y)

#function that returns two values
myfunc <- function(y=y, x=x){
  m <- summary(lm(y~x))
  c1<-m$fstat[1]
  c2<-m$coefficients[1]
  c(c1,c2)
 }

 ddply(df, .(ID), summarize, myfunc(y=y,x=x))
```

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
     ID           ..1
1   ID1  69.477838332
2   ID1  -0.279584776
3  ID10 396.792689197
4  ID10  -0.359578656
```

What I would like to get is this:

```
     ID            c1            c2
1   ID1  69.477838332  -0.279584776
2  ID10 396.792689197  -0.359578656
```

I know I could change the output from ddply to get the desired result, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can change in my function or in the ddply call that would give the desired output. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: This looks like a reshape long to wide to me.

Comment: just change the last line of your function to `cbind(c1, c2)`

Comment: Thank you @Sotos!

Comment: To extract coefficients from a a linear model, see also this example of the [purrr package from the tidyverse](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/).